# how to loop through async data in angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an angular component that fetches data from the server, then transforms it before assigning it to a variable:

```
class Component {
  data = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(data).pipe(
      map(data => { this.data = this.transformData(data); })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  transformData(data) {
    // data is an array of data
    return data.map(item => item);
  }
}
```

*The above is a simplified version of what I'm doing, the transform method does more but it's irrelevant.*

then I try to do a for loop using the data but it wont show me anything, and there are no errors being thrown either:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data|async">
  {{ item.prop1 }} {{ item.prop2 }}
</div>
```

I'm not sure why this is happening - I'm used to react where I pass in props or update the state and the component re-renders, what's the workflow in angular?

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824710/angular2-ngfor-not-working-while-fetching-data-from-api-on-ngoninit) but it still wont show me any data:

```
class Component {
  data = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(data).pipe(
      map(data => { this.data = this.transformData(data); })
    ).subscribe();
  }

  transformData(data) {
    // data is an array of data
    // notice 'of()'
    return of(data.map(item => item));
  }
}
```

To clarify, I do see the value of `this.data` change when I console.log, but the html is not rendering the data

Comment: Before i attempt to help you with this: Please post all of the relevant code, what is `store` ?. Also, Why isn't your `Component` implementing `OnInit`. The OnInit method will not be called otherwise. Use a constructor(){} to call your function if you do not intend to use ngOnInit's lifecycle event.

Comment: the code is minimal, I removed everything that is not relevant to the question. The store is a redux store

Comment: well... The fact that you are not explicitly implementing OnInit in your component may be error enough to cause this behaviour.

Comment: I'm implementing it, but it's removed from this because that's not where the issue is

Comment: @Joel Whether or not implementing `OnInit`, Angular will call the method if it exists. `Angular instead inspects directive and component classes and calls the hook methods if they are defined. Angular finds and calls methods like ngOnInit(), with or without the interfaces.` Here is the official docs: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#interfaces-are-optional-technically

Comment: Well, calling a function that returns data in the onInit method (and you are not getting any results back) seems very relevant... But thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: @Joel I see your point, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `async`, you can pass `Observable` or `Promise` to `*ngFor`. Therefore, you need to assign the return value of `this.store.select` to `data` without `subscribe`:

```
class Component {
  data: Observable<any>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.store.select(data).pipe(
      map(result => { return this.transformData(result); })
    );
  }

  transformData(data) {
    // data is an array of data
    return data.map(item => item);
  }
}
```

If you won't do any modifications in `transformData` method, you can remove `pipe`.

```
class Component {
      data: Observable<any>;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.data = this.store.select(data);
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're doing in the `transformData` method. You're essentially returning the same `data` as is.

Try this though:

```
class Component {
  data$: Observable<any[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = this.store.select(data).pipe(
      map(data => this.transformData(data))
    );
  }

  transformData(data) {
    return data.map(item => item);
  }
}
```

And then in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">
  {{ item.prop1 }} {{ item.prop2 }}
</div>
```

Comment: transformData was simplified because it's not the focus of the question

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the error doesn't lie within your `service`.

Then maybe you can try something like this:

```
class Component {
  private data = Observable<Array<any>>;

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.store.select(data).pipe(
      map(data => { this.data = this.transformData(data); })
    );
  }

  private transformData(data): Observable<any> {
    // data is an array of data
    // notice 'of()'
    return of(data.map(item => item));
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data | async">
    {{item.prop}}
</div>
```

Since I cant see how your service looks like, *i'm going to have to assume*...

I would advice you to use promises here instead as I've found them more easy to work with in cases where async is sought after. Also, instead of passing the pipe here, do it in your service. That way, you only have raw data to spit out to the HTML-view, no conversions in the controller needed, and that way you know that you have data (because you can get it from the service at an earlier stage and not the controller).

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```js
    class Component {
      data = [];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.store.select(data).pipe(
          map(data => this.transformData(data))
        ).subscribe(result=> { this.data =result});
      }

      transformData(data) {
        // data is an array of data
        return data.map(item => item);
      }
    }
```